# Detect which Guava version is used?

Tags: java, guava

I have a project that uses an old Cassandra driver library, which relies on deprecated features of Guava that have been removed in release 20. I was thinking about adding a test that fails when someone accidentally increases the version of Guava from 19 to 20.

**How can I programmatically find out which Guava version is used?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a simple way to get access to the version, but here is a solution that works for me:

```
@Test(expected = ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void mustNotUpgradeToGuava20_asItIsIncompatibleWithCassandra() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.google.common.graph.Graph");
}
```

This test passes up to Guava 19 and will fail with Guava 20. The `Graph` class is just the first hit of added classes that I found in the release notes.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a version string from files under META-INF/ in the guava.jar. At runtime you'll need to use appropriate `ClassLoader` instance in order to load the META-INF/ files you want. You can either use Guava's [`Resources`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html) utility class to load a resource with a unique name directly or you can iterate through resources with the same name across multiple `jar` files using `$someGuavaClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResources(String)`. If you go with the latter then you will need to use `someGuavaClassName` that will exist in the version you are testing against. `Resources` itself has been in Guava since 1.0 and I don't suspect it going anywhere anytime soon so that should be a safe class to use.

I tested the following on Guava 20.0 and 12.0 and it worked for both. I suspect it will work for all relatively recent versions of Guava:

```
public class GuavaVersionFetcher {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(determineGuavaMavenVersion());
        System.out.println(determineGuavaManifestVersion());
    }

    public static String determineGuavaMavenVersion() throws IOException {
        String resourceName = "META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResource(resourceName).openStream()) {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        }
        return properties.getProperty("version");
    }

    public static String determineGuavaManifestVersion() throws IOException {
        Enumeration<URL> resources = Resources.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            Manifest manifest;
            try (InputStream inputStream = resources.nextElement().openStream()) {
                manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
            }
            Attributes mainAttributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
            String symbolicName = mainAttributes.getValue("Bundle-SymbolicName");
            if ("com.google.guava".equals(symbolicName)) {
                return mainAttributes.getValue("Bundle-Version");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
20.0
20.0.0
```

Note: If the Guava team ever moves away from using Maven the first method may no longer work so I suggest using the manifest method.